# Cleaning up git rewritten histories that got merged back together?

Tags: git, github, version-control

I have a Git repository that goes back to 2007. It started out as a CVS repo that was converted to SVN and then Git.

A few months ago I did some `filter-branch`-ing to reduce repository size and spinoff some unrelated projects into their own repos.

The result is that the history in the remaining "main" repository is now a mess and I have many commits that look identical (same message and timestamp) but different SHA1 on parallel tracks of the tree.

Is there a way to rewrite this as a complete linear history? I'd like to loop over the history and basically just take the last commit at any given day and keep only that commit for that day, but combine all the unique commit messages from that day.

That would give me a linear chronological history. I understand any experiments made on development branches will look a little odd (as if I made the change on master and then later backed it out). That's fine.

Git really should keep some sort of meta-history that traces the lineage of rewritten and rebased commits back to the original commits.

Comment: "Git really should keep some sort of meta-history that traces the lineage of rewritten and rebased commits back to the original commits." http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/A+bad+workman+blames+his+tools It sounds like you've got quite the mess, and it's not Git's fault. IMO your best bet will be to do a massive manual rewrite locally, then force push to GitHub. (This has significant implications that you should be aware of, but it's unlikely to make your situation worse. The kinds of problems caused by rewriting and force-pushing are the ones you're trying to fix now.)

Comment: The alternative to lots of manual fixing is to just stop caring about it. The history is history. Just continue in a clean way from now on.

Answer (score 0):

There was a simple fix for this after all.

I looked for two obviously duplicate commits (a milestone production release several months ago that pre-dated all the filter-branch craziness) and used `git replace` to stich the two duplicates together.

So now the old the history and the recent history are both linear, there's just a localized bulge of craziness in between I'll just leave alone.